# EntityFramework migration get current DbContext in custom SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have a custom class from SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator.

```
public class CustomMigration : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    protected override void Generate(AlterColumnOperation alterColumnOperation)
    {
        // ....
        // ....
    }
}
```

In the method Generate is it possible execute a sql command on current database to apply the migration? Example:

```
public class CustomMigration : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    protected override void Generate(AlterColumnOperation alterColumnOperation)
    {
        // I need to get the DATABASE CONTEXT HERE!!!
        // to execute a sql command
        var c = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('MyDB', 'Collation')");
    }
}
```

Thanks!